# TypeError: embedding(): argument 'indices' (position 2) must be Tensor, not int

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to get the predictions for an RNN model. However, while generating the predictions I'm having this error:

> TypeError: `embedding()`: argument 'indices' (position 2) must be Tensor, not int

```
class RNNClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim,vocab_size, output_dim, batch_size):
        super(RNNClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.layer_dim = layer_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(embedding_dim,hidden_dim, layer_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.dense = nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_dim, out_features = 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden  = torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_()
        print(hidden.shape)

        embeds = self.embedding(x)
        lstm_out, hidden = self.rnn(embeds, hidden.detach())
        print(lstm_out.shape)
        lstm_out = lstm_out[:,-1,:] #getting the last timestep
        print(lstm_out.shape)
        
        out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
        out = self.dense(lstm_out)

        sig_out = self.sigmoid(out)

        return sig_out, x
```

**Predictions code and error snippet**

```
def get_predictions(model, loader):
   all_preds = torch.tensor([])
   for batch_x, batch_y in enumerate(loader):
        #batch_x, batch_y = sample[batch_x], sample[batch_y]
        preds = model(batch_x)
        preds = torch.round(preds)
        all_preds = torch.cat((all_preds, preds), dim=0)
    return all_preds


    with torch.no_grad():
        network.eval()
        prediction_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size)
        prediction_loader = next(iter(prediction_loader))
        train_preds = get_predictions(network, prediction_loader)
```

[image]

Comment: the `embedding` `Module` being an instance of `nn.Embedding`, it expects a `torch.LongTensor` of indices. Perhaps, you are passing an integer. You can check it with `print(type(x))`.

Comment: Yes, the `type` of  **x** returns a `torch.tensor` which I had already converted before passing the inputs. Still the **error** is not resolved.